# How to take a pic using expo react native camera?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera

I have just started using React Native with Expo so I am kind of confused.
So, I have made a camera component which I imported in the main screen. Everything looks good. But I can't take pictures. I cannot click the snap icon and save the image. Is there a component that I missed? I have only posted the CameraComponent function below.

**CameraScreen.js**

```
const CameraScreen = () => {


    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
            setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
    }, []);

    if (hasPermission === null) {
        return <View />;
    }
    if (hasPermission === false) {
        return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }

    const takePicture = () => {
        if (Camera) {
            Camera.takePictureAsync({ onPictureSaved: onPictureSaved });
        }
    };

    const onPictureSaved = photo => {
        console.log(photo);
    }

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera style={styles.camera}
                type={type}
                ref={(r) => {
                    camera = r
                }}>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.flip}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.button}
                            onPress={() => {
                                setType(
                                    type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                                        ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                                        : Camera.Constants.Type.back
                                );
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.text}> Flip </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.Shot}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={takePicture}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}> Shot </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Camera>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    camera: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        paddingBottom: 25,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10
    },
    flip:{ 
    },
    Shot:{
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 25,
        color: 'white',
    },
});

export default CameraScreen
```

The button(Shot) in the bottom should automatically take and save image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Camera.takePictureAsync({ onPictureSaved: onPictureSaved });
```

> A callback invoked when picture is saved. If set, the promise of this method will resolve immediately with no data after picture is captured. The data that it should contain will be passed to this callback. If displaying or processing a captured photo right after taking it is not your case, this callback lets you skip waiting for it to be saved.

You should use the async promise from `takePictureAsync` function

```
Camera.takePictureAsync()
    .then(onPictureSaved);


//your onPictureSaved function
const onPictureSaved = ({ uri, width, height, exif, base64 }) => {
    console.log(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version (~13.2.1) of `expo-camera`, you need to use `useRef` inside functional components.

Firstly, create a ref named `cameraRef`.

```
const cameraRef = useRef(null);
```

Then, create your `Camera` component with `TouchableOpacity` inside.

```
    <Camera type={CameraType.back} ref={cameraRef}>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={async () => {
            if (cameraRef.current) {
              let photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
              console.log(photo.uri);
            }
          }}
        >
     </View>
   </Camera>
```

Now, you are ready to take photographs!

And, an additional information, if any error happens related to your first shoot attempt, there is a warning in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#takepictureasyncoptions) of `expo-camera`:

> Make sure to wait for the onCameraReady callback before calling this
> method.